# Using a string to create a Liquid variable

Tags: shopify, liquid

In my shopify store, I am using SuperFields in order to customize my site, though my question isn't about the app. On one of my pages, I need the value for the following:

```
variant.metafields.sf_{{ collection.title | downcase }}[meta_tag_key]
```

The value should be 0 or 1. If I evaluate the statement directly, such as:

```
{if variant.metafields.sf_{{ collection.title | downcase }}[meta_tag_key] =1%}
```

It throws an error when I render the page: Unexpected character '{'

I've also tried the following:

```
{% capture defaultImage %}variant.metafields.sf_{{ collection.title | downcase }}[meta_tag_key]{% endcapture %}
{% assign test = defaultImage %}
```

But 'test' is considered nil and doesn't return any value. I have tried to search for answers here and on the shopify forum, but, as my clumsy post title suggests, I'm having a hard time concisely searching for a solution to this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
{% assign metafield-key = collection.title | downcase | prepend: "sf_" %}
{% assign key = variant.metafields[metafield-key][meta_tag_key] %}
{% if key == 1 %}
  Do the twist !
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a % sign in your code. Hence the error message. Your if statement started with {% and not just {

Answer (score 0):

If you working in liquid then you have to use {% %} for defining any variable & also for condition in shopify. You can't use { this.